# Ubuntu 18.04 installation on a VMWare stucks

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, vmware

I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04.01 64-bit in a VMWare virtual machine.  The VM is on a Windows 10 machine and the Ubuntu ISO image is on the same hard disk.

I selected to use a 50 GB single file for the VM and it told me it would use Easy Install.  It has been stuck at this screen for over an hour.  What's wrong?  What do I do to recover?

I don't have enough reputation to post the screenshot, but you can find it here:  https://s8.postimg.cc/yvqogzidx/ubuntu_18_04_stuck.png

Comment: Solved.  The VM had been set up with only 1 GB of memory.  As soon as I raised it to 2 GB, the installation resumed.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the installation can hang in a VM if there is insufficient memory (e.g., only 1 GB).  Bumping the VM memory up to 2 GB caused the installation to resume.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Fusion 10.1.5, giving the VM 2 cores and 4GB of RAM, and installation of 18.04 (amd64) still hung right at the language selection page.  I used the same ISO to install 18.04 in a VirtualBox VM, and it worked, so the problem appears to be with VMWare Fusion.

Also tried 16.04 (amd64) under VMWare Fusion 10.1.5, and though the install completed, the machine hangs at the login prompt.  Have also used that same 16.04 ISO with VirtualBox, without a problem.

Fusion 10.1.5 seems to need some work (this is my first time using it).